If $A$ is abelian and $m > 0$, then $A \otimes \mathbb{Z}_m \simeq A/mA$
Note: $\otimes$ means $\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$.
I am currently trying to show that if $A$ is abelian and $m > 0$, then $A \otimes \mathbb{Z}_m \simeq A/mA$. My idea is to use the First Isomorphism Theorem for $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
At the moment, I have defined my mapping to be given by $\phi : A \to A \otimes \mathbb{Z}_m$, where $\phi(a) = a \otimes 1$. I have shown that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, and $\phi$ is onto, but I am not entire sure if it would be possible to obtain $\ker(\phi) = mA$ in order to be able to apply the First Isomorphism Theorem. If it were to be possible, then we would be done. But it's just this step I am having a bit of trouble with.
Appreciate some help.

Duplicate question, please use site search. Also, use that isomorphisms are invertible homomorphisms. Also it is true for all integers $m$. The proof is not different for $0$ or non-zero.

For learning tensor products I can highly recommend https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf by Keith Conrad.
